# Lightswitch: Clear a datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

In a screen I have a few datagrids that for set is set to not "auto execute". To load the screen the user has to press a "refresh" button.

After data has been loaded into such a grid, when the parent object that the grids change the loaded data remains but belongs to an other object.

Is there anyway to clear the DataGrid on when the parent object changes?

Comment: Can't you just modify the query to return no results given a particular condition?